# What is the FAA Approval Basis for an FMS upgrade on a Part 25 aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-certification

Does anyone know of a recent approval for an upgrade from a Universal UNS-xx FMS  to a Universal UNS-1Ew FMS on a FAA registered aircraft, other than a TC, TC update or an STC?

I am looking for the specific guidance which would allow a FAA Principal Inspector to do a Field Approval and/or sign the Flight Manual Supplement approval.

Comment: What aircraft type? What is the current certification basis (TC/STC)? Generally, the only way you can get an update approved by Field Approval is if there is already an existing cert basis (an STC) for the change or the change is minor. A change requiring a new AFMS is typically not considered a minor change, so you'll probably need the rights to use an existing STC for your aircraft type (assuming one exists). Have you tried asking Universal?